# Problem with a SELECT CASE WHEN THEN ELSE END sentence

Tags: sql, oracle

I need a query for Oracle SQL that, if the quotient of a division (COUNT (prod_low) / COUNT (prod_total)) is less than 0.005 shows this quotient; and in another case, gives me the specific cases that are part of the dividend of that operation (prod_low).

It could also be worth it if in both cases it showed me the list prod_low, and in each row, the percentage of the division mentioned above. Or failing that, instead of said percentage, a phrase that says 'alert: >= 0.5%' or 'no alert: <0.5%' for each line based on the calculated quotient.

Thank you in advance!

```
SELECT CASE 
       WHEN (COUNT (prod_low) / COUNT (prod_total)) > 0.005 THEN (COUNT (prod_low) / COUNT (prod_total))
       ELSE prod_low
       END 
FROM(
SELECT DISTINCT p1.prods AS prod_total, prod_low
FROM products p1
LEFT JOIN(SELECT DISTINCT p2.prods AS prod_low, p2.id AS id2
FROM products p2
WHERE p2.price < 10)
ON p1.id = id2)
```

Comment: A [mcve] would make things clearer here. You can probably find a more straight-forward solution.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
WITH prod_counts AS (
  SELECT
    COUNT(*) AS prod_total,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN p.price < 10 THEN p.prods ELSE NULL END) AS prod_low
  FROM products p
)
SELECT
  prod_low,
  (prod_low / prod_total) * 100 AS percentage,
  CASE
    WHEN (prod_low / prod_total) < 0.005 THEN 'no alert: <0.5%'
    ELSE 'alert: >= 0.5%'
  END AS alert_status
FROM prod_counts;
```

This query uses a WITH clause to calculate the prod_total and prod_low counts, and then calculates the percentage and alert status for each row.

Note that I've assumed the prod_low and prod_total are based on the number of products with a price less than 10, and the total number of products, respectively. If you want to filter by some other criteria, you can modify the COUNT(CASE...) line accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! prod_total and prod_low should be columns that reflect the codes of all the products and cheap products respectively, instead of the count of them, as you suggest. My goal is to show the list of cheap products (prod_low) if quotient is higher than 0.005, and otherwise only this quotient. However, it could be great if in any case the result is the list prod_low with a column that reflects the quotient count(prod_low)/count(prod_total) for each row, and maybe another one who says alert or not alert (the same for each row based on the quotient. Maybe it's too difficult.

Answer (score 0):

You have not given any sample data or your expected output but you may be able to get the output without any self-joins using conditional aggregation. If you want

```sql
SELECT id,
       CASE
       WHEN COUNT(CASE WHEN price < 10 THEN prods END) / COUNT(prods) > 0.005
       THEN COUNT(CASE WHEN price < 10 THEN prods END) / COUNT(prods)
       ELSE MAX(CASE WHEN price < 10 THEN prods END)
       END
FROM   products
GROUP BY id
```

or:

```sql
SELECT CASE
       WHEN COUNT(CASE WHEN price < 10 THEN prods END) / COUNT(prods) > 0.005
       THEN COUNT(CASE WHEN price < 10 THEN prods END) / COUNT(prods)
       ELSE MAX(CASE WHEN price < 10 THEN prods END)
       END
FROM   products
```